# How build a list dynamically and pass/save user selected values from an HTML form to server?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, combobox, server-side

I think in this case I need to write a client side script that onpageload/onchange gets options from server & builds a list dynamically. & stores new options to server via some JavaScript script. I will prefer to save user input in a file on server. I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Did you try something? Which server you are using?

Comment: I am searching for how to do it still. But seems file i/O have some concerns from browser access. Actually what I require at the moments is just some kind of advise or guideline for that from you experience people(like my be php would be good here in spite of javascript) as I put only my thinking/idea there how to solve there. I am using localhost, apache 2.2.14 (IPV6 enabled). One more thing I will be thankful if you answer me is is it safe/preferable to use javaScript in connection with user may have turned off JavaScripts. I know there are alternatives too but what for an optimal use.

Comment: Why do you want to store data as files? There are plenty of easy database SQL or noSQL ones that make this easier.

Comment: And for javascript, it depends your target. We are not anymore in 1995. Apps like youtube, gmail, twitter, etc... little by little erode the Javascript paranoia, but it is still present, and depends on the population you target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the stack we use for our web app and that works more or less the way you describe:

1. the user load an HTML page
2. the page make an ajax call and get the options as a JSON(either it exists already in the database, or a new option set is generated)
3. the json is rendered using a JS templating engine ([PURE](http://beebole.com/pure) in our case)
4. the user change something
5. the same JSON is modified and sent by a POST to the server
6. the server read that JSON and store it in the database(you would write the data to your file). And then go back to the step 4, to wait for another user change.

Comment: thanX a Lot Mic, it will help me a long way :-)

Comment: thanX again, Actually no reason:-) I was just thinking that it(i.e. file) may be could work quickly may be & once I see it working, I mean whole stack as u defined it then I will convert to MySQL.